# How to get a object member in string format

Tags: powershell

I'm not at all sure what the heck I'm doing wrong, I'm running the manage-bde (command line to return bitlocker encryption status) and piping it to a select-string to catch the specific encryption percentage/status with a very specific regex.  Select string for some reason returns the whole line, but a property called "Matches" returns the EXACT information I need, but it's a Matchinfo object.  There's a method called ToString but it doesn't return at all what I need, seems to be the object info.  I just want the output in string format to display in a write-progress gui.

note: quite new to powershell still.

```
$act = Invoke-Expression -Command "manage-bde -status C:" | select-string -Pattern "(?<=(Percentage Encrypted:)).*"  | Select-Object -Property Matches -Last 1

$act.toString()| Out-Host
```

Comment: All great answers, thank you, mjolinor gets answer credit but all fantastic methods, I feel stupid for missing out-string, all great solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MatchInfo objects can be confusing. Try this:

```
$act = Invoke-Expression -Command "manage-bde -status C:" |
 select-string -Pattern "(?<=(Percentage Encrypted:)).*"  |
 Select-Object -Property Matches -Last 1

$act.matches[0].value
```

Alternatively:

```
(manage-bde -status C:) -match '^\s+Percentage Encrypted:' -replace '\D+(\d+%)','$1'
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the design principles of Powershell is that most everything can be treated as an object (versus as text as in other administrative scripting languages). Since manage-bde is not a Powershell tool (rather a plain ol' command line tool) it doesn't work with PS as easily as a tool designed for PS. In the case of BitLocker there are dozen or so PS cmdlets. In particular `Get-BitLockerVolume` sounds like a near equivalent to `manage-bde -status`

However if you want to stick with manage-bde, then you can use the `out-string` cmdlet to generate string output from objects. So the following may be what you want.

```
$act = Invoke-Expression -Command "manage-bde -status C:" | 
   select-string -Pattern "(?<=(Percentage Encrypted:)).*"  | 
   Select-Object -Property Matches -Last 1 |
   out-string

$act| Out-Host
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make almost anything a string by using the following:

`[string](code_to_be_parsed)`

### Example

I can create a string array from the `ping` command:

`$test = [string[]](ping google.com)`

Which gives me the result:

```
# empty line
Pinging google.com [74.125.200.101] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.200.101: bytes=32 time=302ms TTL=36
Reply from 74.125.200.101: bytes=32 time=302ms TTL=36
Reply from 74.125.200.101: bytes=32 time=302ms TTL=36
Reply from 74.125.200.101: bytes=32 time=306ms TTL=36

Ping statistics for 74.125.200.101:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 302ms, Maximum = 306ms, Average = 303ms
```

When I do a `$test.count` it returns 11, which is in fact the exact number of lines, each being a string inside of the array.

Answer (score 0):

my answer is based on vasili syrakis' post. got to this page with the exact question as the OP.

```
$encryptionstatus = [string[]](manage-bde -status c:)
$encryptionstatus[9] | Out-Host
```